# how do i plot a phase plane diagram using maple

Tags: plot, ode, maple

Hello I was wondering if anyone could help me, I'm trying to use maple to generate a phase plane diagram of the system below.
On the diagram I want to mark on the equilibrium points that I found for the following system they are (x,y)=(0,2) and (1,0)

the system is $(dx/dt)=-2x-y+2$ and $(dy/dt)=xy$
The attempt i made is below

```
DEplot(sys, [x(t), y(t)], t = 10 .. -10, x = -3 .. 3, y = -3 .. 3, [[x(0) = 0, y(0) = 2]], [[x(0) = 0, y(0) = 1]], stepsize = .1, linecolor = blue, thickness = 2, arrows = medium);
```

where

sys := {diff(x(t), t) = -2*x(t)-y(t)+2, diff(y(t), t) = x(t)*y(t)}

and the graph it produced is

[image]

can anyone confirm if this is the correct phase plane diagram for the system above?

Comment: updated my post

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just need to include more initial values.

```
restart; with(DEtools): with(linalg):with(plots):
sys := {diff(x(t), t) = -2*x(t)-y(t)+2, diff(y(t), t) = x(t)*y(t)}
initialdataset:={seq(seq([x(0)=a,y(0)=b],a=-5..5),b=-5..5)}:
DEplot(sys, [x,y],t=-3..3,initialdataset,x = -6..6, y = -6..6,
   colour=black, thickness=2, style=line, linestyle=1, axes=boxed,
   linecolor=red, scaling=constrained, arrows=medium);
```

[image]